# Angular6 Firebase User State for Component outside Router-Outlet

Tags: angular, firebase, validation, firebase-authentication, navbar

I'm a beginner to web technologies and trying to write an Angular app(for mobile and web) which uses firebase for authentication.

My App Component Html will be like this.

```
<NavBar Component>

<SideBar Component> //visibility toggled based on action from the navbar

<Router Outlet>
```

I have used a few routes like /home , /checkout, /user/login and /user/profile.

An item in my NavBar will be displayed as 'Login' or 'User Profile' based on the loggedIn status, to let the user navigate to either /user/login or /user/profile

The Authentication Service on firebase works fine and I'm able to get the logged in user information and change the router link in the navbar item.

**The problem comes when I refresh the window.** When the window is refreshed, the firebase Auth user is null and it takes a few seconds for it to set up and send the user data. So the navbar item reads 'Login' for few seconds and then changes to 'User Profile'

Since the NavBar does not come inside router-outlet, I'm not able to use a Resolver service to solve this purpose.

Should I use local storage to solve this? or Is there any other better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to skin the ngCat, but this is a great use case for a Router Guard. Router guards are great for authentication and a better place to handle security concerns around navigation. I highly recommend you refactor your code to make sure all your components that require authentication to be part of a route that can be guarded.

The essence of the router guard is the CanActivate method, where you define the criteria around who can (or can't) proceed to load the protected page. It's a simple thumbs up/thumbs down boolean return, but the less common form can return an Observable, which you can use to block execution while waiting for the initial authentication call return from Firebase.

```
    import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
    ...
    @Injectable({
       providedIn: 'root',
    })
    ...
    export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
    ...
    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public router: Router) {}
    ...
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
       const authenticated: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
       this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
           if (!firebaseUser) {
               this.router.navigate(['/user/login']);
               authenticated.next(false);
           } else {
               authenticated.next(true);
           }
           authenticated.complete();
       });
       return authenticated;
   }
```

Reference the guard in your root routing table:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [{ path: 'user', loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule' }],
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    ...
```

To recap, when you refresh the page (e.g. reload app), canActivate will fire and your page will not load until there is an authStateChange from Firebase, which is chained to an observable. So while it takes the same amount of time to load, you aren't seeing the in-between transitions.

Note that the call is wrapped by the AngularFireAuth module, but the onAuthStateChanged pattern is referenced in the general Firebase documentation as the preferred way to track authentication changes.

Good luck!

References:

[Angular route guards 101](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)

[Firebase user management](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this approach. I was wondering if I could get this done by any other way than moving the NavBar and SideBar as part of Routed components because I wanted them to be fixed even when moving between different pages

Comment: One approach you can take is to use nested router-outlets, attach the Auth Guard above to the root, but always return true. You can also have multiple layers of Router Guards to validate the user at the second outet, but not affecting your core components that you want to remain regardless of the authentication state. That is a sure-fire way to acheive your goal, albeit perhaps an 'off-label' use of router outlet. You would have to post cost in order for me to recommend a better solution.